# External login callback doesn't redirect to authorize endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

My external login callback handler would successfully set the aspnet cookies, but not redirect to the authorize endpoint to continue the OIDC flow in OpenIddict. For example, this:

```cs
app.MapMethods("callback/login/github", new[] { HttpMethods.Get, HttpMethods.Post }, async (HttpContext context) =>
{
    var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictClientAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(authenticationType: "ExternalLogin");
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, result.Principal!.FindFirst("id")!.Value));

    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = result.Properties!.RedirectUri
    };

    // properties.RedirectUri ignored!!!
    return Results.SignIn(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), properties);
});
```

... returned a 200 OK result instead of a 302 to the specified Redirect Url, completely ignoring the property passed to `Results.SignIn`

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that my project was targeting .Net 6.x, but [a bug was fixed in 7.x](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36934) that allows the ASP.NET cookie authentication handler to use the redirect URL that was specified in the `AuthenticationProperties`.

The [OpenIddict Mimban sample](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Mimban/Mimban.Server) targets 8.0 and works great, but posting my own question + answer here to help others that might still be targeting .Net 6.0.

Solution is to either:

1. Target 7.x (or later)
2. Manually return the redirect result, e.g.

```cs
await context.SignInAsync(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), properties);
return Results.Redirect(properties.RedirectUri ?? "/");
```

Comment: This is indeed the correct approach when targeting .NET 6 (or earlier versions) 